# Insert bulk data into big-query without keeping it in streaming buffer

Tags: node.js, async-await, google-bigquery, synchronization

My motive here is as follow:

1. Insert bulk records into big-query every half an hour
2. Delete the record if the exists

Those records are transactions which change their statuses from: pending, success, fail and expire.

BigQuery does not allow me to delete the rows that are inserted just half an hour ago as they are still in the streaming buffer.

can anyone suggest me some workaround as i am getting some duplicate rows in my table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better course of action would be to:

- Perform periodic [loads](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data) into a staging table (loading is a free operation)
- After the load completes, execute a [MERGE statement](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_statement).

You would want something like this:

```
MERGE dataset.TransactionTable dt
USING dataset.StagingTransactionTable st
ON dt.tx_id = st.tx_id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE dt.status = st.status
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (tx_id, status) VALUES (st.tx_id, st.status)
```

Comment: i am already using DML statements to delete and insert rows , but it's causing query too complex error also there are several other fields to be updated for each record.
are you suggesting that i should maintain two tables ( temp , final ) ?

Comment: Yes, using a level of indirection could help

Comment: can you update your answer to update the whole row with all the fields ?

Comment: also i need to load data every half an hour into the temporary table .. how do i manage duplicates there ? i would've to truncate the temp table after my operations ?

Comment: You need to list the columns to update or insert explicitly, and I don't know the names of the columns in your table, so you'll need to write the complete query yourself. Yes, you should overwrite the temp table whenever you load into it.

Comment: i got that , but even after using a staging table i cannot delete the staging table data after 30 min as streaming insert will require 90 min to do those operations

Comment: would creating a new table every 30 minutes and delete afterwards solve this ? is it a standard solution ?